# "Close" function event listener

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I'm new to Javascript so I'm sorry if this this questions has been answered elsewhere - I have looked for a solution but I'm either missing the answer, or just not understanding it when I see it.

So basically, I have a number of divs which when clicked, show previously hidden divs.  In order to re-hide the div I have a cross icon in the corner of each with an ID of cross.  This event listener is supposed to hide the divs (var expand) but it only works with the first div on the page, i thought the for loop would hide all...?

Any help?

example code:

```
var cross = document.querySelectorAll("#cross");

cross.addEventListener("click", function(hide){
for (i = 0; i < expand.length; i++) {
expand[i].style.display = "none";
}
});
```

Comment: Ids are supposed to be unique within the document. Use classes instead of ids. Also, you can't attach listener to a collection of elements. Iterate through the collection, and attach the listeners to the elements each member of the collection refers.

Comment: `var cross = document.querySelectorAll("#cross");` is getting all elements with the id of 'cross' but it's a little illogical to use as there should only be 1 element with such an id so `.getElementById('cross')` would be a little more fitting. Like @Teemu said, use classes since you're using multiple elements.

Comment: In addition to the above comments, what is `expand`? You don't appear to have it defined. Could you please share your HTML as well?

Comment: Yeah that was a dumb mistake - cross has been changed to class instead of ID, thanks.  However, i'm still getting this error:

" designJS.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: cross.addEventListener is not a function
    at designJS.js:13".

var expand is the collection of divs that I want to toggle hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can't have multiple icons with `id="cross"`. IDs have to be unique. So you should use `class="cross"`.

`querySelectorAll` returns a collection, you have to loop over them.

```
var cross = document.querySelectorAll(".cross");
for (var i = 0; i < cross.length; i++) {
    cross[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        for (i = 0; i < expand.length; i++) {
            expand[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    });
}
```

I suspect the event listener function here is not correct, though. This will hide *all* the elements in `expand`, but you probably only want to hide the ones in the same DIV as the cross that was clicked. But without seeing your HTML I don't know how to find the related DIVs. To get you moving in the right direction, `this` inside the function will be the icon they clicked on, you can use `this.parentNode` to find the container, and use that to find other elements in the same container.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes a lot of sense, and its also cleared the error I was getting on that line of code.  However, the next line of code is a simple var initialising: 

"var profExpand = document.getElementByClassName("professionalExpand");"

but im now getting an errorsaying "document.getElementByClassName is not a function".  I thought it could possibly be syntax error (missing } maybe) but ive looked over the code and validated it and cant see any errors.

Comment: It's called `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: Got it, thank you. Wonder why that didn't show when I put it through the validator.

Comment: It's not invalid syntax, it's just a property that doesn't exist.

Comment: Gotcha, well its fully functional now so thanks for your help - much appreciated.